# Blazor Server Net 6 Serilog not Logging

Tags: blazor, serilog

I have a Blazor Server app and using Serilog. Sinking to File, Server, and SEQ. Below is my Program.CS code:

```
//********** Add Configuration for Serilog : Begin **********
//Add Configuration for Serilog Configuration

IConfigurationRoot SerilogConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true).Build();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.ReadFrom.Configuration(SerilogConfig);

});

//********** Add Configuration for Serilog : End **********


app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

Log.Information("Application Starting Up in 3");
Log.Information("Application Starting Up in 2");
Log.Information("Application Starting Up in 1");
```

Appsettings.JSON

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithEnvironmentUserName",
      "WithEnvironmentName",
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithProcessID",
      "WithThreadID"
    ],
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Seq", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://webmail:5341",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }//,
      //{
      //  "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      //  "Args": {
      //    "connectionString": "DefaultConnection",
      //    "SinkOptionsSection": {
      //      "tableName": "Serilog",
      //      "autoCreateSqlTable": true
      //    }
      //  }
      //}
    ]
  }
```

The code logs the information in the Program.CS but I also have Log.Information in other areas that are not getting logged. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, just for grins I created a new Blazor server project and copied all the Serilog code from my main program and it logs just fine. Something else is breaking it. I deleted all the Serilog packages and re-installed them and still no luck. Something is breaking Serilog after the app.run.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Stupid me. For every Try-Catch-Finally statement I had I was Closing and Flushing the Log. Removed those and starting getting log entries.